# Disabling SmartScreen in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, application-launch, microsoft-smartscreen

SmartScreen was introduced to warn users about malicious installs on computers running Windows 8.1.

It was designed to help protect users from the threats that come from unauthorized or malicious software and apps.  However, for those computer users who know what they’re doing, take advantage of anti-virus software, and acquire software and apps from legitimate sources, the SmartScreen is just another thing in the way of getting to install or use something they’ve already checked out.

How do I disable SmartScreen and save an additional step in the installation or launching of application on a PC? What precautions should be taken once SmartScreen is disabled, if any?

Comment: @Ramhound Thats fine, although your answer doesn't show the instructions using 8.1 (the difference is probably negligible). Hopefully the question & answer(s) will be of help to anyone wishing to do so.

Comment: My instructions are accurate for `Windows 8.1` you might want to try following them. The control panel wasn't removed in `Windows 8.1`. Change the tag from `Windows 8` to `Windows 8.1` and I will remove my downvote.  The instructions would not be any different, if you really want `Windows 8.1`, I can update the answer in time.

Comment: @Ramhound Found the tag, you had to type 8.1 and not Windows 8.1 for it to show.

Answer (score 5):

While I don't advise actually doing this because even the most caustious people WILL make a mistake eventually and SmartScreen is design to stop that I will go ahead and post the instructions to do this.

1. Open up the classic control panel, and select the System and
   Security link [image: Step 1]
   <sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/sshot-215.png))</sub>
2. Now select the Action Center option.[image: Step 2]
3. Once you are in the Action Center expand the security list, and scroll down looking for the Windows SmartScreen option. Once you have found it click the change settings link.[image: Step 3]
   <sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/sshot-160.png))</sub>
4. You will most likely be prompted by UAC to enter your password, now you can totally turn off the SmartScreen Filter. Change the radio button from the default to the bottom option.[image: Step 4]
   <sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/sshot-3_thumb7.png))</sub>

[How-To Geek -> How to Turn Off or Disable the SmartScreen Filter In Windows 8](https://www.howtogeek.com/75356/how-to-turn-off-or-disable-the-smartscreen-filter-in-windows-8/)

> Can I turn SmartScreen on or off? Yes. Here's how:
>
> 1.Open Internet Explorer.
>
> 2.Click the Safety button, point to SmartScreen Filter, and then click either Turn off SmartScreen Filter or Turn on SmartScreen Filter.
>
> 3.In the Microsoft SmartScreen Filter dialog box, click OK.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-smartscreen-and-how-can-it-help-protect-me-1c9a874a-6826-be5e-45b1-67fa445a74c8#ie=ie-8)

[Additional Instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/930168)